Logstash Elasticsearch output plugin creates a single document index in Elasticsearch
i am newer in ELK, My LOGSTASH 7.8.x loop indefinitely and insert only one row in Elasticsearch !
Here is my sample example :
sample log
2021-07-18 09:15:30,000 INFO Sample log message 01
2022-07-18 10:20:45,111 ERROR Sample log message 02
2023-07-18 11:20:45,222 DEBUG Sample log message 03
2024-07-18 12:20:45,333 WARN Sample log message 04

conf file
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/sample.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    close_older=> "1 second"
 }
}

filter {
    grok {
          match => { "resource" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log_level} %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" }
         }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "sample_logs"
    document_id => "%{my_doc_for_logs}"
    document_type => "_doc"
    codec => "json"
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

By running logstash as follow :
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/sshd.conf --log.level debug
1- Only one line is inserted in Elasticsearch index : sample_logs
2- I have to click on CTRL + C to stop indefinitely loop of logstash, image below :
debug image
cheking Elasticsearch data : only 1 row instead of 4 is inserted !!!
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/sample_logs/_search?size=1000" | jq .
Elastic Data
1- Only one line is inserted in elasticsearch index : sample_logs
2- I have to click on CTRL + C to stop indefinitly loop of logstash, image below :

The problem is the document_id.
document_id => "%{my_doc_for_logs}"

In your case Elasticsearch indexes all the documents with one and the same id.
Try deleting it, elasticsearch will be indexing with auto generated ids.
If you want a value to assign it, you can use this pattern.
Example:
mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][id]" => "%{[host][name]}_%{some_field}" } }

document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"

Log of indefinitely loop debug below :
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:19.583 [pool-3-thread-1] cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:19.701 [pool-3-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:19.701 [pool-3-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:22.781 [logstash-pipeline-flush] PeriodicFlush - Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:24.592 [pool-3-thread-1] cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:24.715 [pool-4-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:24.716 [pool-4-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:27.781 [logstash-pipeline-flush] PeriodicFlush - Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:29.596 [pool-4-thread-1] cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:29.728 [pool-3-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:29.728 [pool-3-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:32.781 [logstash-pipeline-flush] PeriodicFlush - Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:34.599 [pool-3-thread-1] cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:34.739 [pool-4-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:34.740 [pool-4-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:37.781 [logstash-pipeline-flush] PeriodicFlush - Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:39.604 [pool-4-thread-1] cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:39.752 [pool-3-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:39.753 [pool-3-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:42.782 [logstash-pipeline-flush] PeriodicFlush - Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:44.607 [pool-3-thread-1] cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:44.762 [pool-4-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:44.762 [pool-4-thread-1] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2024-07-22 09:21:47.782 [logstash-pipeline-flush] PeriodicFlush - Pushing flush onto pipeline.


Hello [Murat K.] the problem of one row inserted is solved and thank you so much, but unfortunately,  the message comes again and again until i click on CTRL + C, any idea please, you can check debug image above : cgroup - One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu

It is a debug message and I think it cause no problems. I think your user has no permission to reach the files. Here are some similar problems: 1- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/one-or-more-required-cgroup-files-or-directories-not-found-in-logstash/337348  2-https://discuss.elastic.co/t/one-or-more-required-cgroup-files-not-found-of-cgroup/163054    3- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-is-shutting-down-after-connecting-to-elastic-search-due-to-one-or-more-required-cgroup-files-or-directories-not-found/347448/3

And can you please copy and paste the logs in question? Because Stackoverflow does not like screenshots. It doesn't allow copying and not good for screen readers (for blind people).

Logs had been added, thank you Murat.K, still checking the urls you sent me, it seems the problems is more than permissions!

Murat K., hello, this looping message block me and there is no sincere answer in internet, no effective answer to this ! can you help please?
